# PHPDoc comment return type

Tags: php-7

I have a question about the defined return type in an abstract class.
Is @return Travel[] an array or a class?

The second problem that arise from it is that I always get an error in the line: if (!travel instanceof Travel) because it is never an instance of Travel.

How could it be solved?

I have tried.

```
Class Travel extends Action {
  protected function getTravel() {
    return ['UK', 'Italy', 'Spain'];
  }
}

abstract class Action {
/**
* @return Travel[]
*/
  abstract protected function getTravel(Vehicle $vehicle);
}

final public function call(Vehicle $vehicle) {
  $travels = $this->getTravel($vehicle);
  foreach ($travels as $travel) {
    if (!travel instanceof Travel) {
      throw new RuntimeException("This should not happen")
    }  
  }
}
```

Comment: Your method `getTravel` returns a list of strings(`['UK', 'Italy', 'Spain']`). `@return Travel[]` is just an annotation for documentation, it doesn't change what your methods actually returns.
If you want `getTravel` to return `Travel` objects, you need to create `Travel` objects.

Comment: Also, it seems your example is missing context. Where is the `call` function defined? What is the `$this` reference pointing to?